# combinatorics four digits out of three

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

With three given digits (1,2,3), how many unique four-digit combinations can be made if all three digits must be present but may be repeated?

Example of correct combinations: (1,2,3,3) (1,1,2,3) (1,2,2,3) ...
Incorrect: (1,1,2,2) (no "3" present)

Comment: Are the sequences ordered?

Comment: The sequences may be ordered or not. How may unique combinations are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible interpretations of the problem: (i) How many **strings** of length $4$ are there or (ii) how many $4$-element **multisets** are there? I find the string interpretation more natural.

**Counting strings:** The digit that is repeated can be chosen in $3$ ways.

For each of these choices, the locations for the repeated digit can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.

For each of these ways, the leftmost open slot can be filled in $2$ ways.

Now the word is determined.

**Counting multisets:** Once we have decided which digit is repeated, it's over.

Comment: I do not fully understand your answer. For counting strings, is there a formula for this that might explain things better for a beginner?

Comment: On looking at your question again, I am less sure of what you intend to count. Is $2123$ one of the possibilities? Or must the symbol that occurs twice occur in an adjacent pair? Counting problems are very sensitive to wording. Please send an answer. You may not get a reply for a while, I will be out, but you definitely will get a reply in $6$ hours or less.

Comment: @Bollit, when you see "for each of these choices," that means you have to multiply.  For the strings (ordered sequences), there are three ways to pick the repeated digit.  It appears in two of the four places, so the digit that appears twice can be selected in $$\binom{4}{2} = 6$$ ways.  That leaves two open slots in which to place the remaining numbers.  You can fill the leftmost open slot in two ways, which leaves you only one way in which to place the remaining number.  Therefore, there are $$3 \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 3 \cdot 6 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 36$$ possible strings.